# Can't solve this eigenvalues problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I can't seem to solve it

$$
\left [  \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array} \right ] 
$$

I want to get the eigenvalues based on that variable $a$. I've already attempted  $A-\lambda\cdot I$ and I got that $\lambda=-1$ but can't advance on the rest of the eigenvalues.

Comment: What you want to find in this ?

Comment: You need to tell us what you're trying to do and what you have already attempted. You can't simply _solve_ a matrix, learn the correct terminology and don't abuse the site. Downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues are $-1$ and $\frac{1}{2}(-1+a \pm \sqrt{a^2+2a+17})$.
The eigenvectors are $(0,1,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{4}(-1+a \pm \sqrt{a^2+2a+17}),0,1)$